# When starting minikube set to --kubernetes-version v1.7.6, startup fails due to kubeadm attempting to use kube-dns

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

On my mac and Linux boxes (Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia), when attempting to start minikube compatible with v.1.7.6, the startup fails when it tries to run the `/usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase addon kube-dns` command.  The problem is that `kube-dns` does not appear to be a valid option in kubeadm in kubernetes 1.7.x.

Following advice on the web, I have tried to use `--bootstrapper=localkube`, which fails with the message `Error getting cluster bootstrapper: Unknown bootstrapper: localkube.`

Is there a way to get minikube to be compatible with 1.7.6?  1.7.x is what is running in our production cluster, so for compatibility in testing, running minikube at this version is needed.

This is one variation I have tried

```
    $  minikube stop && minikube delete && rm -rf ~/.minikube && rm -rf ~/.kube
    $ minikube start --kubernetes-version v1.7.6 
    Starting local Kubernetes v1.7.6 cluster...
    Starting VM...
    Downloading Minikube ISO
     170.78 MB / 170.78 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s
    Getting VM IP address...
    Moving files into cluster...
    Downloading kubeadm v1.7.6
    Downloading kubelet v1.7.6
    Finished Downloading kubeadm v1.7.6
    Finished Downloading kubelet v1.7.6
    Setting up certs...
    Connecting to cluster...
    Setting up kubeconfig...
    Starting cluster components...
    E1019 08:40:54.829107   13340 start.go:297] Error starting                    
    cluster:  kubeadm init error 
    sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm init --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml --skip- 
    preflight-checks &&
    sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase addon kube-dns
     running command: : running command: 
    sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm init --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml --skip-preflight-checks &&
    sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase addon kube-dns
```

When I log into the cluster, I can verify that kube-dns is not a valid option.

```
    $ minikube ssh
                              _             _            
                 _         _ ( )           ( )           
       ___ ___  (_)  ___  (_)| |/')  _   _ | |_      __  
     /' _ ` _ `\| |/' _ `\| || , <  ( ) ( )| '_`\  /'__`\
     | ( ) ( ) || || ( ) || || |\`\ | (_) || |_) )(  ___/
     (_) (_) (_)(_)(_) (_)(_)(_) (_)`\___/'(_,__/'`\____)

     $ /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase addon --help
     Invoke subsets of kubeadm functions separately for a manual install.

    Usage:
      kubeadm alpha phase [flags]
      kubeadm alpha phase [command]

    Available Commands:
      certs       Generate certificates for a Kubernetes cluster.
      kubeconfig  Create KubeConfig files from given credentials.
      validate    Run end to end validation

    Use "kubeadm alpha phase [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```

If I just take the default, which is 1.10.0, minikube does startup, but I am encountering a problem with our application, which may be due to a kubernetes api change.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It appears the best way to solve a problem is to ask someone else, and then the answer will come to you.

I downloaded an older version v0.25.2 of minikube and it resolved this problem.  I had tried this yesterday but did not go far enough back in time.